# Why can I add numbers with int(s[0]) + int(s[1]) but not int(s[0] + s[1])?

Tags: python

I don't understand why this works perfectly:

```
ticket = input()

half1 = int(ticket[0])+int(ticket[1])+int(ticket[2])
half2 = int(ticket[3])+int(ticket[4])+int(ticket[5])

if half1 == half2:
    print("Lucky")
else:
    print("Ordinary")
```

but this doesn't:

```
ticket = input()

half1 = int(ticket[0] + ticket[1] + ticket[2])
half2 = int(ticket[3] + ticket[4] + ticket[5])

if half1 == half2:
    print("Lucky")
else:
    print("Ordinary")
```

This second case always prints `ordinary` unless both half are exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try inspecting what half1 and half2 are?

Comment: also did you try inspecting what exactly `ticket[0] + ticket[1] + ticket[2]` yields? Also please format your code with `\`\`\``.

Comment: sorry in advance for my ignorance. if you mean using the type() function on the 2 half variables then yes I tried and they're both integers

Comment: No, what they mean is that you should look at the *actual values* both variables (half1, half2) take. I.e. just print them! The second version does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Because `"1" + "2" == "12"` and `1 + 2 == 3`. Types matter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a little printing so you can see whats the problem.

```
>>> ticket = ["10","92","8","33","30","37"]
>>> print (ticket[0] + ticket[1] + ticket[2])
10928
>>> print(type(ticket[0] + ticket[1] + ticket[2]))
<class 'str'>
>>> print (int(ticket[0])+int(ticket[1])+int(ticket[2]))
110
>>> print(type(int(ticket[0])+int(ticket[1])+int(ticket[2])))
<class 'int'>
```

So `+` operator between two strings just adds second string after the first string. Same operator between two integers or other numbers sums *values*. There is big diiference, as you can see.